# How To Make My Form Clear After A User Clicks Send

Tags: html

Hi This Is My fist time o stack overflow but i would just like to find out how do i make my code clear after a user clicks send in my form here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Order Now</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Order Now</h2>
            <div class="row100">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="inputBox">
                    <input type="text" name="" required="required">
                    <span class="text">Discord Name And Discrimator</span>
                    <span class="line"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
               <div class="col">
                    <div class="inputBox">
                    <input type="text" name="" required="required">
                    <span class="text">Email Address</span>
                    <span class="line"></span>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row100">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="inputBox">
                    <input type="text" name="" required="required">
                    <span class="text">Email</span>
                    <span class="line"></span>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="inputBox">
                          <div class="select">
                          <select name="format" id="format">
                          <option selected disabled>Choose Your Package</option>
                         <option value="basic">Basic Bot</option>
                         <option value="advanced">Advanced Bot</option>
                         <option value="premuim">Premuim Bot</option>
                         <option value="Website">Website</option>
                   </select>
                   <span class="line"></span>
                 </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row100">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="inputBox textarea">
                        <textarea required="required"></textarea>
                        <span class="text">Type Your Message Here...</span>
                        <span class="line"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="row100">
            <div class="col">
                <input type="submit" value="Send">
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>     
    </body>
</html>
```

I dont know what should i use should i create a separate file i am new to coding thou i think maybe i should use  and use JavaScript but i dont know is there anyone open to help me.sorry if its kinda a noob question

Comment: How you submit your "form"? And there is no actual `<form>` element on page, nor any JS to submit it. Usually you don't manually clear normal forms, since user will be redirected to back-end and form will automatically clears after that

Comment: so would i have to add a ```<form>``` element at the start and at the end </form>

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some JS for that, and you have to make some modifications to your code.
For submitting data you should use `<form></form>`html element with ID and then target it with JS to do a `reset()` on it.

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-platform-q457v?file=/clear-form.js:0-67)

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Order Now</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleo.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <h2>Order Now</h2>
          <div class="row100">
            <form id="my-form" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="submit()">
              <div>
                <label>Discord name and Discrimator : </label> <input type="text" />
              </div>
              <div><label>Email : </label> <input type="text" /></div>
              <div>
                <label>Type your text here : </label>
                <textarea></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="inputBox">
                  <div class="select">
                    <select name="format" id="format">
                      <option selected disabled>Choose Your Package</option>
                      <option value="basic">Basic Bot</option>
                      <option value="advanced">Advanced Bot</option>
                      <option value="premuim">Premuim Bot</option>
                      <option value="Website">Website</option>
                    </select>
                    <span class="line"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <input type="submit" value="Send" />
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      </body>
      <script src="clear-form.js"></script>
    </html>
```

clear-form.js :

```
function submit() {
  document.getElementById("my-form").reset();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Order Now</h2>
            <div class="row100">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="inputBox">
                    <input type="text" name="" required="required">
                    <span class="text">Discord Name And Discrimator</span>
                    <span class="line"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
               <div class="col">
                    <div class="inputBox">
                    <input type="text" name="" required="required">
                    <span class="text">Email Address</span>
                    <span class="line"></span>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row100">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="inputBox">
                    <input type="text" name="" required="required">
                    <span class="text">Email</span>
                    <span class="line"></span>
                </div>
                </div>
                <d  iv class="col">
                    <div class="inputBox">
                          <div class="select">
                          <select name="format" id="format">
                          <option selected disabled>Choose Your Package</option>
                         <option value="basic">Basic Bot</option>
                         <option value="advanced">Advanced Bot</option>
                         <option value="premuim">Premuim Bot</option>
                         <option value="Website">Website</option>
                   </select>
                   <span class="line"></span>
                 </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row100">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="inputBox textarea">
                        <textarea required="required"></textarea>
                        <span class="text">Type Your Message Here...</span>
                        <span class="line"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
            </div>     
            <div class="row100">
                <div class="col">
                        <div class="btnsubmit" style="border: solid 1px; width: 85px; padding: 10px; cursor: pointer ;border-radius: 8px; background-color: greenyellow;">
                            submit
                        </div>
               </div>
            </div>
</body>

<script>
     let send = document.querySelector(".btnsubmit")
    console.log(send)
send.addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("okay")
    var container = document.querySelector(".container");
    let inputs = container.getElementsByTagName('input');
         for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
             if(inputs[index].type =="text")
             inputs[index].value = '';
         }
})
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I hope this answer will help you